# Getting gazebo and cob_bringup to work

Tags: ros, gazebo-worlds

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to get the `cob_bringup` package to work on ubuntu 10.04. I have installed the system according to the instructions found here http://www.ros.org/wiki/Robots/Care-O-bot/electric. Additional packages are installed from apt or cloned/checked out from their repositories.

When running `$ roslaunch cob_bringup_sim robot.launch` a bunch of includes fail due to the absence of `.../ros/...` in some of the paths. I was able to get around this but if fails with this error msg:

```
parent link 'arm_7_link' of joint 'sdh_palm_joint' not found.  The Boxturtle urdf parser used to automatically add this link for you, but this is not valid according to the URDF spec. Every link you refer to from a joint needs to be explicitly defined in the robot description. To fix this problem you can either remove this joint from your urdf file, or add "<link name="arm_7_link" />" to your urdf file
```

(Note that is does not specify any path)

Is there some better way of getting the system up and running? We have tried installing from source but every time that ends up much worse. The same goes for newer versions of ubuntu (among others).

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/12692/getting-gazebo-and-cob_bringup-to-work/) by [tommyo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1669/tommyo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 27 on 2012-01-19

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I managed to at least spawn COB in simulation without errors on oneiric/installed from .debs, but it does not react to /cmd_vel messages. See (unanswered) question here: http://answers.ros.org/question/3474/using-care-o-bot-in-simulation-on-electric

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-01-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0